# Geography in GeoPandas?

Tags: geopandas, geography-data-type

Is there a way to make GeoPandas work with geographies?

If GeoPandas were used with pygeos, is there a way to force all calculations (ST_Distance, ST_Length, etc.) to be geodesic?  How do I tell it *not* to use Shapely, but PyGeos (or whatever) and that it should do geodesic math?

I like using GeoPandas, but in order to do work with spherical geographies it seems necessary to put the data into PostGIS and have it do spherical calculations.  Can GeoPandas be forced into geoid operations?  Is it just a matter of setting the proper CRS on a dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It emphasizes that there should be only one question asked per question.  I recommend reviewing http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115 for tips on how to structure a good question.

Answer (score 3):

GeoPandas currently supports only planar operations as its geometry engine (shapely/pygeos) is planar. There is a vague discussion to bring support of spherical geometry in the future but based on the recent user survey, there's not much of demand, so it is not a priority for the team.